# Is there a latex template that makes a page look like a math notepad?

Tags: templates

is there a class or template to make a LaTeX page look like a math-ruled notebook/pad page? Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do it by using `TikZ` and the `background` package (needs two runs to work correctly):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{background}

\SetBgContents%
{   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw [line width=0.3pt,color=gray,step=0.5cm] (current page.south west) grid (current page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-14]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: From the version 2.0 of `background` there's a new syntax for the options; your settings can be written as `\backgroundsetup{
contents= {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw [line width=0.3pt,color=gray,step=0.5cm] (current page.south west) grid (current page.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
scale=1,
angle=0}` (the `\SetBg...` family of commands can still be used with the new version).

Comment: There's no need to explicitly load `tikz`; the `background` package internally loads it if the user hasn't loaded before.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Thanks for the info about the loading, and I'm aware there's a new version. The `MiKTeX` updater does not yet have it, and I was to lazy to install it manually. Great update, it will keep me from looking up the commands every time I use it :)

Comment: (Just a question: is it possible to have the text aligned to the background lines?)