# How do I customize a beamer block that look like this?

Tags: beamer, block

I desire to customize block in beamer that looks like this image:
[image]

I have tried to use column style but most times I have been unable to write the same length of reasonable text in each column unlike my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[shrink=30]
\frametitle{~}
    \begin{columns}
        \column{.45\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{~}
            \blindtext
        \end{block}
        \column{.45\textwidth}
        \begin{block}{~}
            \blindtext
        \end{block}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I do not want it to have a global effect on the beamer, one should be able to call for it when need be.

Comment: Could you clarify your question ? What do you mean by that looks like the image ? Should it be an image, should it have two columns ...

Comment: @BambOo I mean two-column notebook like the image above in my question.

Comment: Well, if you want something looking close to a notebook, you can start here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229919/background-notebook-template-with-spiral. But it will require some effort