# Notepad background for beamer

Tags: beamer

In [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229919/background-notebook-template-with-spiral), Gonzalo Medina proposed the following solution for making an article look like a notebook with binder:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[contents={}]{background}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\ShadowXshift{0.5ex}
\def\ShadowYshift{-0.5ex}

\makeatletter
\define@key{educnotebook}{spiralnumber}{\def\SpiralNumber{#1}}
\define@key{educnotebook}{nbcolorbg}{\def\NbColorBg{#1}}
\define@key{educnotebook}{minorgridcolor}{\def\MinorGridColor{#1}}
\define@key{educnotebook}{majorgridcolor}{\def\MajorGridColor{#1}}
\define@boolkey{educnotebook}{majorgrid}[false]{
\ifKV@educnotebook@majorgrid 
  \def\DrawMajorGrid{
    \path[clip,rounded corners=10pt]
        ([xshift=-30pt,yshift=20pt]current page text area.north west) rectangle
        ([xshift=30pt,yshift=-20pt]current page text area.south east);
    \draw[\MajorGridColor,opacity=0.3]
          ([xshift=30pt,yshift=-20pt]current page text area.south east) grid[step=10mm]
          ([xshift=-30pt,yshift=20pt]current page text area.north west);
  }
\else
  \def\DrawMajorGrid{\relax}
\fi
}
\define@boolkey{educnotebook}{minorgrid}[false]{
\ifKV@educnotebook@minorgrid 
  \def\DrawMinorGrid{
    \path[clip,rounded corners=10pt]
        ([xshift=-30pt,yshift=20pt]current page text area.north west) rectangle
        ([xshift=30pt,yshift=-20pt]current page text area.south east);
    \draw[\MinorGridColor,opacity=0.3]
          ([xshift=30pt,yshift=-20pt]current page text area.south east) grid[step=1mm]
          ([xshift=-30pt,yshift=20pt]current page text area.north west);
  }
\else
  \def\DrawMinorGrid{\relax}
\fi
}
\define@choicekey+{educnotebook}{spiralposition}[\val\nr]{left,right,top}[left]{%
  \ifcase\nr\relax
    \def\SpiralPosition{
      ([xshift=9pt,yshift=3pt-\Valor*\textheight/(\SpiralNumber-1)]current page text area.north west)
    }
    \def\RotateAngle{0}
  \or
    \def\SpiralPosition{
      ([xshift=-9pt,yshift=-5pt-\Valor*\textheight/(\SpiralNumber-1)]current page text area.north east)
    }
    \def\RotateAngle{180}
    \def\ShadowXshift{-0.5ex}
    \def\ShadowYshift{-0.5ex}
  \or
    \def\SpiralPosition{
      ([yshift=-19pt,xshift=5pt+\Valor*\textwidth/(\SpiralNumber-1)]current page text area.north west)
      }
    \def\RotateAngle{270}
  \fi
}{}

\setkeys{educnotebook}{
  nbcolorbg=white,
  minorgrid=false,
  majorgrid=false,
  minorgridcolor=black!20,
  majorgridcolor=black!60,
  spiralposition=left,
  spiralnumber=15
  }
\def\RotateAngle{0}
\def\ShadowXshift{0.5ex}
\def\ShadowYshift{-0.5ex}

\makeatother

\tikzset{
spiral/.pic={
  \draw[rotate=\RotateAngle,
    draw=black,
    left color=black!70,
    right color=black!60,
    middle color=gray!40
    ] 
    (-1.1,-0.35) rectangle ++(10pt,10pt);
  \draw[
    rotate=\RotateAngle,
    double=gray!80,
    double distance=1pt,
    ]
    (-1,-0.2) arc (40:-250:10pt and 2pt);
  \draw[
    rotate=\RotateAngle,
    double=gray!80,
    double distance=1pt,
    ]
    (-1,-0.05) arc (40:-250:10pt and 2pt);
  }
}

\newcommand\EducNotebook[1][]{%
\begingroup
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \setkeys{educnotebook}{#1}%
  \backgroundsetup{
    scale=1,
    opacity=1,
    color=black,
    angle=0,
    contents={
      \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
      {
      \draw[rounded corners=10pt,fill=\NbColorBg,drop shadow={shadow xshift=\ShadowXshift, shadow yshift=\ShadowYshift}]
        ([xshift=-30pt,yshift=20pt]current page text area.north west) rectangle
        ([xshift=30pt,yshift=-20pt]current page text area.south east);
      \foreach \Valor in {0,1,...,\numexpr\SpiralNumber-1\relax}
        \pic at \SpiralPosition {spiral};
      \DrawMajorGrid
      \DrawMinorGrid
      }  
      }
    }
  \BgMaterial
  }
\endgroup
}

\EducNotebook

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

How could I accurately transfer this template to beamer, so that the text in each frame is surrouned by the same rounded rectangle note page with binder shown here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Step 1

Create a background image using the answer you found:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[contents={}]{background}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\ShadowXshift{0.5ex}
\def\ShadowYshift{-0.5ex}

\makeatletter
\define@key{educnotebook}{spiralnumber}{\def\SpiralNumber{#1}}
\define@key{educnotebook}{nbcolorbg}{\def\NbColorBg{#1}}
\define@key{educnotebook}{minorgridcolor}{\def\MinorGridColor{#1}}
\define@key{educnotebook}{majorgridcolor}{\def\MajorGridColor{#1}}
\define@boolkey{educnotebook}{majorgrid}[false]{
\ifKV@educnotebook@majorgrid 
  \def\DrawMajorGrid{
    \path[clip,rounded corners=10pt]
        ([xshift=-30pt,yshift=20pt]current page text area.north west) rectangle
        ([xshift=30pt,yshift=-20pt]current page text area.south east);
    \draw[\MajorGridColor,opacity=0.3]
          ([xshift=30pt,yshift=-20pt]current page text area.south east) grid[step=10mm]
          ([xshift=-30pt,yshift=20pt]current page text area.north west);
  }
\else
  \def\DrawMajorGrid{\relax}
\fi
}
\define@boolkey{educnotebook}{minorgrid}[false]{
\ifKV@educnotebook@minorgrid 
  \def\DrawMinorGrid{
    \path[clip,rounded corners=10pt]
        ([xshift=-30pt,yshift=20pt]current page text area.north west) rectangle
        ([xshift=30pt,yshift=-20pt]current page text area.south east);
    \draw[\MinorGridColor,opacity=0.3]
          ([xshift=30pt,yshift=-20pt]current page text area.south east) grid[step=1mm]
          ([xshift=-30pt,yshift=20pt]current page text area.north west);
  }
\else
  \def\DrawMinorGrid{\relax}
\fi
}
\define@choicekey+{educnotebook}{spiralposition}[\val\nr]{left,right,top}[left]{%
  \ifcase\nr\relax
    \def\SpiralPosition{
      ([xshift=9pt,yshift=3pt-\Valor*\textheight/(\SpiralNumber-1)]current page text area.north west)
    }
    \def\RotateAngle{0}
  \or
    \def\SpiralPosition{
      ([xshift=-9pt,yshift=-5pt-\Valor*\textheight/(\SpiralNumber-1)]current page text area.north east)
    }
    \def\RotateAngle{180}
    \def\ShadowXshift{-0.5ex}
    \def\ShadowYshift{-0.5ex}
  \or
    \def\SpiralPosition{
      ([yshift=-19pt,xshift=5pt+\Valor*\textwidth/(\SpiralNumber-1)]current page text area.north west)
      }
    \def\RotateAngle{270}
  \fi
}{}

\setkeys{educnotebook}{
  nbcolorbg=white,
  minorgrid=false,
  majorgrid=false,
  minorgridcolor=black!20,
  majorgridcolor=black!60,
  spiralposition=left,
  spiralnumber=15
  }
\def\RotateAngle{0}
\def\ShadowXshift{0.5ex}
\def\ShadowYshift{-0.5ex}

\makeatother

\tikzset{
spiral/.pic={
  \draw[rotate=\RotateAngle,
    draw=black,
    left color=black!70,
    right color=black!60,
    middle color=gray!40
    ] 
    (-1.1,-0.35) rectangle ++(10pt,10pt);
  \draw[
    rotate=\RotateAngle,
    double=gray!80,
    double distance=1pt,
    ]
    (-1,-0.2) arc (40:-250:10pt and 2pt);
  \draw[
    rotate=\RotateAngle,
    double=gray!80,
    double distance=1pt,
    ]
    (-1,-0.05) arc (40:-250:10pt and 2pt);
  }
}

\newcommand\EducNotebook[1][]{%
\begingroup
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \setkeys{educnotebook}{#1}%
  \backgroundsetup{
    scale=1,
    opacity=1,
    color=black,
    angle=0,
    contents={
      \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
      {
      \draw[rounded corners=10pt,fill=\NbColorBg,drop shadow={shadow xshift=\ShadowXshift, shadow yshift=\ShadowYshift}]
        ([xshift=-30pt,yshift=20pt]current page text area.north west) rectangle
        ([xshift=30pt,yshift=-20pt]current page text area.south east);
      \foreach \Valor in {0,1,...,\numexpr\SpiralNumber-1\relax}
        \pic at \SpiralPosition {spiral};
      \DrawMajorGrid
      \DrawMinorGrid
      }  
      }
    }
  \BgMaterial
  }
\endgroup
}

\EducNotebook
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage[landscape,hmargin=2cm,vmargin=1.7cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
~
\end{document}
```

### Step 2

Use the resulting image as background for your beamer presentation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{document2}
}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\vskip0.4cm}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\vskip0.4cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]