# How can I make note paper in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to make note paper, such as this
[image]

in LaTeX. I know that you can achieve this with TikZ. I wanted to ask if there exist dedicated packages for this purpose. Or do you have other hints?

Comment: maybe http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188164/how-to-use-latex-to-print-a-document-to-look-like-a-lined-notebook just without text?

Comment: look at https://gist.github.com/numberknight/dd73bb60b5d40dcc9e37, this has even the right colours

Comment: @samcarter -  Could you repeat your comment as an answer, so I can accept it? (I am not sure that this makes sense since the question is closed.)

Comment: @MWc I am sorry, but as the question is closed as a duplicate, it is not possible to add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

"Look at gist.github.com/numberknight/dd73bb60b5d40dcc9e37, this has even the right colours." - [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter)

Comment: @MWc Don't worry, no harm was done.