# Two liner notebook

Tags: line-spacing, rules, addlines

Planning to prepare two liner sheets for improving the handwriting. Any better solution than this ?

```
    \begin{document}
\vspace {0.25cm}
\rule{\paperwidth}{0.1pt}
\vspace {0.25cm}
\rule{\paperwidth}{0.1pt}
\vspace{.4cm}
\rule{\paperwidth}{0.1pt}
\vspace {0.25cm}
\rule{\paperwidth}{0.1pt}
\vspace{.4cm}\rule{\paperwidth}{0.1pt}
\vspace {0.25cm}
\rule{\paperwidth}{0.1pt}
\vspace{.4cm}\rule{\paperwidth}{0.1pt}
\vspace {0.25cm}
\rule{\paperwidth}{0.1pt}
\vspace{.4cm}\rule{\paperwidth}{0.1pt}
\vspace {0.25cm}
\rule{\paperwidth}{0.1pt}
\vspace{.4cm}
\vspace {0.25cm}
\rule{\paperwidth}{0.1pt}
\vspace {0.25cm}
\rule{\paperwidth}{0.1pt}
\vspace{.4cm}
\rule{\paperwidth}{0.1pt}
\vspace {0.25cm}
\rule{\paperwidth}{0.1pt}
\vspace{.4cm}\rule{\paperwidth}{0.1pt}
\vspace {0.25cm}
\rule{\paperwidth}{0.1pt}
\vspace{.4cm}\rule{\paperwidth}{0.1pt}
\vspace {0.25cm}
\rule{\paperwidth}{0.1pt}
\vspace{.4cm}\rule{\paperwidth}{0.1pt}
\vspace {0.25cm}
\rule{\paperwidth}{0.1pt}
\vspace{.4cm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \textwidth should better define the length instead of paperwidth

Comment: Not necessarily, since it is to emulate a notebook, but it doesn't begin on the left side of the sheet with this code.

Comment: you could automate it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295254/how-can-i-make-note-paper-in-latex?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I would use a software similar to MS Excel for this task if is just for personal practicing purposes.