# Fixing headings so text is not off line

Tags: sectioning, formatting, backgrounds

I'm working to create an environment where I can take notes in LaTeX so it looks like notebook paper and handwriting. My code so far is as follows (I included graphics, tables, text, and headings, because I wanted to see how they looked):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz, background, titling, setspace,titlesec,booktabs,float}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=.25in,top=1.125in,bottom=.125in]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\backgroundsetup{%
 position=current page.center,
 angle=0,
 scale=1,
 contents={%
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
    [
      normal lines/.style={gray, very thin},
      every node/.append style={black, align=center, opacity=1}
    ]
    \foreach \y in {0.71,1.41,...,25.56}
      \draw[normal lines] (0,\y) -- (8.5in,\y);
    \draw[normal lines] (1.25in,0) -- (1.25in,11in);
    \node (t) [font=\LARGE, anchor=south] at ($(0,25.56)!1/2!(8.5in,25.56)$) {\thetitle};
    \node (d) [font=\large, anchor=south west, xshift=1.5em] at (0,25.6) {\today};
    \node (p) [font=\large, anchor=south east, xshift=-1.5em] at (8.5in,25.56) {p.~\thepage};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}}

\titleformat{\section}[display]{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{}{0em}{}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{augie}

\title{Notes}
\author{Heather Young}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\doublespacing

\section{Math}
$x = \frac {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$ the quadratic formula
$0 = ax^2 + bx + c$ mathematics is awesome

\section{Physics}
$\gamma \to e^+ + e^-$

\section{Coding}
Ever heard of LaTeX? No? Well, it's awesome, and it's what this document is written in.

\section{Diagrams + Doodling}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
    \draw (0,0) -- (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
        \toprule
        X & Y \\
        \midrule
        0 & 1 \\
        \hline
        3 & 5 \\
        \hline
        4 & 7 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Which gives the result

[image]

There are two main problems with this:

1. Not all of the text is on a line, and I'm not sure why. I tried to adjust the title format of the section such that it wouldn't throw anything off, but I don't think that helped at all.
2. Instead of "4" at the top of the page, it should say "Notes" but it doesn't, and again, I'm not sure why.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Credit for the notebook code goes to cfr in the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188164/how-to-use-latex-to-print-a-document-to-look-like-a-lined-notebook). I am using sharelatex.com.

**Edit:** I tried removing the graphic and table to see if either of those was the problem, but some of the text was still not on a line.

Comment: 2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522173/how-to-get-the-value-of-the-document-title-in-latex

Comment: @RunarTrollet, thank you! Unfortunately, I added this code and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: works fine here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this gets a bit closer, keeping tighter control over the various elements to keep to baseline spacing.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz, background, titling, setspace,titlesec,booktabs,float}
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=.25in,top=1.125in,bottom=.125in]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\makeatletter
\backgroundsetup{%
 position=current page.center,
 angle=0,
 scale=1,
 contents={%
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
    [
      normal lines/.style={gray, very thin},
      every node/.append style={black, align=center, opacity=1}
    ]
    \foreach \y in {0.71,1.41,...,25.56}
      \draw[normal lines] (0,\y) -- (8.5in,\y);
    \draw[normal lines] (1.25in,0) -- (1.25in,11in);
    \node (t) [font=\LARGE, anchor=south] at ($(0,25.56)!1/2!(8.5in,25.56)$) {\@title};
    \node (d) [font=\large, anchor=south west, xshift=1.5em] at (0,25.6) {\today};
    \node (p) [font=\large, anchor=south east, xshift=-1.5em] at (8.5in,25.56) {p.~\thepage};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}}

\titleformat{\section}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries}{}{0em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{\baselineskip}
\setlength\lineskip{0pt}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{augie}

\title{Notes}
\author{Heather Young}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\doublespacing

\section{Math}

$\smash{x = \frac {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}}$ the quadratic formula
$0 = ax^2 + bx + c$ mathematics is awesome

\section{Physics}
$\gamma \to e^+ + e^-$

\section{Coding}
Ever heard of LaTeX? No? Well, it's awesome, and it's what this document is written in.

\section{Diagrams + Doodling}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
    \draw (0,0) -- (4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}


    \begin{tabular}[t]{|l|l|}
        \toprule
        X & Y \\
        \midrule
        0 & 1 \\
        \hline
        3 & 5 \\
        \hline
        4 & 7 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect! Would you mind explaining what exactly you did? (Sorry, I'm a bit of a newbie with LaTeX.)

Comment: @heather  just diff against your original:-) I removed the `\large` from the section heading so it doesn't force extra space, I used the titlespacing command do force the space before and after to be `\baselineskip` then I used `\smash` around the quadratic formula which hides its size (it would over-print text if too big) so it doesn't disturb the space

Comment: @heather by hand, if adding something big like a tikzpicture or graphic, you can use `\vspace{5\baselineskip}\smash{\includegraphics{...}` replacing 5 by whatever, that hides the size of what you are adding and forces an exact number of baselines...

Comment: Oh, okay. Then the main thing is controlling each of the elements such that they use an exact number of lines, using commands such as `\smash`. That makes a lot of sense. I just thought it had to do with straight-up size, but that doesn't really matter, as long as the element doesn't take up a fractional line. Thanks!

Comment: @heather if what you are adding is less than a baselineskip tex adds space to force baseline spacing, but if you add an over-sized item it doesn't have a built in way to add space to make it a multiple of baselineskip.  You can automate it more than I suggest here but the macros get (a lot) more complicated and if you are not  automatically trypesetting thousands of documents probably not worth it

Comment: Nope, not typesetting thousands of documents (or even hundreds). =) Thanks again for all your help! You've explained it very clearly.