# Defining tabular \newenvironment with internal \newenvironments?

Tags: tables, macros, environments

**Motivation:** I have developed a template to do engineering homework problems (See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352100/replicating-engineering-computation-pad)), and am now trying to encapsulate the table formating code for problems and their subsections into a `\newenvironment`.

**The Error:** When I run the appended M(N)WE, I get an error message:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<template> \unskip \hfil }
                          \hskip \tabcolsep \endtemplate 
l.24        \begin{given}
                     The weights of the various components of the truck are ...
```

**Question:**

1. Am I using this `\newenvironment` command the wrong way?
2. Is it not possible to include the `&` and `\\` table formating commands in a `\newenvironment`?
3. What is the right way to accomplish the essence of what I am trying to do?

**Attempts:** So far, I have tried the following:

- Placing the formating commands outside the `\newenvironment`, where I would want the macro to place them.
- Using the `environ` package.
- Using `tabu` instead of `tabular`
- Using `\tabular` and `\endtabular` instead of `\begin{tabular}` and `\end{tabular}`

All to no avail.

**Appended M(N)WE:** This is the style I am trying to get to; however, it produces the error I referenced above.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{units}

\newenvironment{problem}{
    \begin{tabular}{l p{5.5in}}
}{
    \end{tabular}
    \pagebreak
}

\newenvironment{given}       { \textbf{Given:}       \vspace{0.125in}   & }{\\}
\newenvironment{asked}      { \textbf{Asked:}       \vspace{0.125in }  &} {\\}
\newenvironment{sketch}     { \textbf{Sketch:}      \vspace{0.125in}   &} {\\}
\newenvironment{equations}  { \textbf{Equations:}   \vspace{0.125in}   &} {\\} 
\newenvironment{solution}   { \textbf{Solution:}     \vspace{0.125in}  &} {\\}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}

    \begin{problem}
        \begin{given} The weights of the various components of the truck are show in the sketch below. \end{given}
        \begin{asked} Replace this system of forces by an equialent resultant force and specify its location measured from $B$. \end{asked}
        \begin{sketch} \begin{center} PUT PICTURE HERE \end{center} \end{sketch}
        \begin{equations} 
            $$\sum F_{x_I} = \sum F_{x_{II}}$$
            $$\sum F_{y_I} = \sum F_{y_{II}}$$
            $$\sum M_{o_I} = \sum M_{o_{II}}$$  

            \vspace{.0625 in}

            $$M_o = F\times d_\perp$$
        \end{equations}
        \begin{solution}
            $$\sum F_x = F_{x_1} + F_{x_2} + F_{x_3} = 0$$
            $$\sum F_y = F_{y_1} + F_{y_2} + F_{y_3} = \unit[3500]{lb} + \unit[5500] {lb} + \unit[1750]{lb} = \unit[10\;750]{lb}$$

            \vspace{.0625 in}

            $$\sum M_B = M_1 + M_2 + M_3$$
            $$\begin{aligned}
                M_1 &= F\times d_\perp = \unit[3500]{lb}(\unit[3]{ft}) &= \unit[10\;500]{ft\cdot lb} \\
                M_2 &= F\times d_\perp = \unit[5500]{lb}(\unit[3]{ft}+\unit[14]{ft}) &= \unit[93\;500]{ft\cdot lb} \\
                M_3 &= F\times d_\perp = \unit[1750]{lb}(\unit[3]{ft}+\unit[14]{ft}+\unit[6]{ft}+\unit[2]{ft}) &= \unit[43\;750]{ft\cdot lb} \vspace{.0625in} \\
                M_B &= \unit[10\;500]{ft\cdot lb} + \unit[93\;500]{ft\cdot lb} +  \unit[43\;750]{ft\cdot lb} &=  \unit[147\;750]{ft\cdot lb}
            \end{aligned}$$
        \end{solution}
    \end{problem}
\end{document}
```

**MWE**: Here is a version that does not use `\newenvironment`, but works, and represents the document I am trying to produce.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{units}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l p{5.5in}}

    \textbf{Given:} \vspace{.125in} & 

        The weights of the various components of the truck are show in the sketch below. \\

    \textbf{Asked:} \vspace{.125in} &  

        Replace this system of forces by an equialent resultant force and specify its location measured from $B$. \\

    \textbf{Sketch:} \vspace{.125in} &  

        \begin{center}PUT PICTURE HERE\end{center} \\

    \textbf{Equations:} \vspace{.125in} &  

        $$\sum F_{x_I} = \sum F_{x_{II}}$$
        $$\sum F_{y_I} = \sum F_{y_{II}}$$
        $$\sum M_{o_I} = \sum M_{o_{II}}$$
        \vspace{.0625 in}
        $$M_o = F\times d_\perp$$ \\

    \textbf{Solution:} \vspace{.125in} &  

            $$\sum F_x = F_{x_1} + F_{x_2} + F_{x_3} = 0$$
            $$\sum F_y = F_{y_1} + F_{y_2} + F_{y_3} = \unit[3500]{lb} + \unit[5500] {lb} + \unit[1750]{lb} = \unit[10\;750]{lb}$$
            \vspace{.0625 in}
            $$\sum M_B = M_1 + M_2 + M_3$$
            $$\begin{aligned}
                M_1 &= F\times d_\perp = \unit[3500]{lb}(\unit[3]{ft}) &= \unit[10\;500]{ft\cdot lb} \\
                M_2 &= F\times d_\perp = \unit[5500]{lb}(\unit[3]{ft}+\unit[14]{ft}) &= \unit[93\;500]{ft\cdot lb} \\
                M_3 &= F\times d_\perp = \unit[1750]{lb}(\unit[3]{ft}+\unit[14]{ft}+\unit[6]{ft}+\unit[2]{ft}) &= \unit[43\;750]{ft\cdot lb} \vspace{.0625in} \\
                M_B &= \unit[10\;500]{ft\cdot lb} + \unit[93\;500]{ft\cdot lb} +  \unit[43\;750]{ft\cdot lb} &=  \unit[147\;750]{ft\cdot lb}
            \end{aligned}$$

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can not do `\newenvironment{given}       { \textbf{Given:}       \vspace{0.125in}   & }{\\}` as it is like doing `{\textbf{Given:}&\\}` as environments form a group, you would  get similar errors. (If you really want that syntax, anything is possible but it's perhaps confusing to use environment syntax for something that is not a group.

Comment: Well, that unfortunately seems to answer questions 1 and 2. Any direction for 3?

Comment: I'll do something but not sure about the intention of `\vspace{0.125in}  ` vspace does nothing very useful in an `l` cell which is horizontal mode

Comment: I am using it to put some vertical space between the subsections of the problem--this makes the output look a lot better when some sections only contain a single line. You can see this in the pdf image in the linked question.

Comment: So I guessed but the fact that adding vertical space in the first cell, in horizontal mode causes space to be added at the end of the row is a more or less accidental and definitely undocumented artefact of the implementation:-)

Comment: Does your engineering course really use pounds and feet? I'm shocked!

Comment: Yea, its a bit of a pain to have to remember two sets of physical constants.

Comment: @MichaelMolter: See [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't work like that: environments form groups.

On the other hand, you're using the wrong tools, in my opinion. Rather than a `tabular` you should use an itemized list.

I changed `unit` into the more powerful `siunitx` package.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example
\usepackage{enumitem,amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newlength{\problemwd}
\AtBeginDocument{\settowidth{\problemwd}{\textbf{Equations:} }}

\sisetup{inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}}
\DeclareSIUnit{\lb}{lb}
\DeclareSIUnit{\ft}{ft}

\newenvironment{problem}
 {\begin{itemize}[align=left,leftmargin=\problemwd,labelwidth=\problemwd,labelsep=0pt]}
 {\end{itemize}\clearpage}

\newcommand{\given}{\item[\textbf{Given:}]}
\newcommand{\asked}{\item[\textbf{Asked:}]}
\newcommand{\sketch}{\item[\textbf{Sketch:}]}
\newcommand{\equations}{\item[\textbf{Equations:}]}
\newcommand{\solution}{\item[\textbf{Solution:}]}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
\given The weights of the various components of the truck are show in the sketch below.

\asked Replace this system of forces by an equivalent resultant force and specify 
       its location measured from $B$.
\sketch \mbox{} % for avoiding centering
  \begin{center} PUT PICTURE HERE \end{center}

\equations
\begin{gather*}
  \sum F_{x_I} = \sum F_{x_{II}} \\
  \sum F_{y_I} = \sum F_{y_{II}} \\
  \sum M_{o_I} = \sum M_{o_{II}} \\[2ex]
  M_o = F\times d_\perp
\end{gather*}

\solution
\begin{gather*}
  \sum F_x = F_{x_1} + F_{x_2} + F_{x_3} = 0 \\
  \sum F_y = F_{y_1} + F_{y_2} + F_{y_3} =
    \SI{3500}{\lb} + \SI{5500}{\lb} + \SI{1750}{\lb} = \SI{10750}{\lb} \\[2ex]
  \sum M_B = M_1 + M_2 + M_3 \\
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
    M_1 &= F\times d_\perp = \SI{3500}{\lb}(\SI{3}{\ft})
      &&= \SI{10500}{\ft\lb} \\
    M_2 &= F\times d_\perp = \SI{5500}{\lb}(\SI{3}{\ft}+\SI{14}{\ft})
      &&= \SI{93500}{\ft\lb} \\
    M_3 &= F\times d_\perp = \SI{1750}{\lb}(\SI{3}{\ft}+\SI{14}{\ft}+\SI{6}{\ft}+\SI{2}{\ft})
      &&= \SI{43750}{\ft\lb} \\
    M_B &= \SI{10500}{\ft\lb} + \SI{93500}{\ft\lb} + \SI{43750}{\ft\lb}
      &&= \SI{147750}{\ft\lb}
  \end{alignedat}
\end{gather*}

\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

Note that the box is due to `showframe`; remove the package and it will go away.

Please, avoid `$$` in LaTeX.

[image]

With a small modification, you can even give an optional font size argument to the environment, in order to accommodate a particularly long problem.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{enumitem,amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newlength{\problemwd}

\sisetup{inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}}
\DeclareSIUnit{\lb}{lb}
\DeclareSIUnit{\ft}{ft}

\newenvironment{problem}[1][\normalsize]
 {#1\settowidth{\problemwd}{\textbf{Equations:} }%
  \begin{itemize}[align=left,leftmargin=\problemwd,labelwidth=\problemwd,labelsep=0pt]}
 {\end{itemize}\clearpage}

\newcommand{\given}{\item[\textbf{Given:}]}
\newcommand{\asked}{\item[\textbf{Asked:}]}
\newcommand{\sketch}{\item[\textbf{Sketch:}]}
\newcommand{\equations}{\item[\textbf{Equations:}]}
\newcommand{\solution}{\item[\textbf{Solution:}]}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}[\footnotesize]
\given The weights of the various components of the truck are show in the sketch below.

\asked Replace this system of forces by an equivalent resultant force and specify 
       its location measured from $B$.
\sketch \mbox{}
        \begin{center} PUT PICTURE HERE \end{center}

\equations
\begin{gather*}
  \sum F_{x_I} = \sum F_{x_{II}} \\
  \sum F_{y_I} = \sum F_{y_{II}} \\
  \sum M_{o_I} = \sum M_{o_{II}} \\[2ex]
  M_o = F\times d_\perp
\end{gather*}

\solution
\begin{gather*}
  \sum F_x = F_{x_1} + F_{x_2} + F_{x_3} = 0 \\
  \sum F_y = F_{y_1} + F_{y_2} + F_{y_3} =
    \SI{3500}{\lb} + \SI{5500}{\lb} + \SI{1750}{\lb} = \SI{10750}{\lb} \\[2ex]
  \sum M_B = M_1 + M_2 + M_3 \\
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
    M_1 &= F\times d_\perp = \SI{3500}{\lb}(\SI{3}{\ft})
      &&= \SI{10500}{\ft\lb} \\
    M_2 &= F\times d_\perp = \SI{5500}{\lb}(\SI{3}{\ft}+\SI{14}{\ft})
      &&= \SI{93500}{\ft\lb} \\
    M_3 &= F\times d_\perp = \SI{1750}{\lb}(\SI{3}{\ft}+\SI{14}{\ft}+\SI{6}{\ft}+\SI{2}{\ft})
      &&= \SI{43750}{\ft\lb} \\
    M_B &= \SI{10500}{\ft\lb} + \SI{93500}{\ft\lb} + \SI{43750}{\ft\lb}
      &&= \SI{147750}{\ft\lb}
  \end{alignedat}
\end{gather*}

\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like a very clean implementation.

Comment: @MichaelMolter The idea is that you only need to mark up the keys. Using `\begin` and `\end` would be possible, but surely more cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

I would give up on table and replace it by something else, for example minipage. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{problem}{}{\pagebreak}

\newenvironment{field}[1]{\par\vspace{0.125in}\noindent\rlap{\textbf{#1:}}\hspace{1in}\begin{minipage}[t]{5in}}{\end{minipage}}
\newenvironment{given}{\begin{field}{Given}}{\end{field}}
\newenvironment{asked}{\begin{field}{Asked}}{\end{field}}
\newenvironment{sketch}{\begin{field}{Sketch}}{\end{field}}
\newenvironment{equations}{\begin{field}{Equation}}{\end{field}}
\newenvironment{solution}{\begin{field}{Solution}}{\end{field}}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{problem}
    \begin{given} The weights of the various components of the truck are show in the sketch below. \end{given}
    \begin{asked} Replace this system of forces by an equialent resultant force and specify its location measured from $B$. \end{asked}
    \begin{sketch} \begin{center} PUT PICTURE HERE \end{center} \end{sketch}
    \begin{equations} 
        $$\sum F_{x_I} = \sum F_{x_{II}}$$
        $$\sum F_{y_I} = \sum F_{y_{II}}$$
        $$\sum M_{o_I} = \sum M_{o_{II}}$$  

        \vspace{.0625 in}

        $$M_o = F\times d_\perp$$
    \end{equations}
    \begin{solution}
        $$\sum F_x = F_{x_1} + F_{x_2} + F_{x_3} = 0$$
        $$\sum F_y = F_{y_1} + F_{y_2} + F_{y_3} = \unit[3500]{lb} + \unit[5500] {lb} + \unit[1750]{lb} = \unit[10\;750]{lb}$$

        \vspace{.0625 in}

        $$\sum M_B = M_1 + M_2 + M_3$$
        $$\begin{aligned}
            M_1 &= F\times d_\perp = \unit[3500]{lb}(\unit[3]{ft}) &= \unit[10\;500]{ft\cdot lb} \\
            M_2 &= F\times d_\perp = \unit[5500]{lb}(\unit[3]{ft}+\unit[14]{ft}) &= \unit[93\;500]{ft\cdot lb} \\
            M_3 &= F\times d_\perp = \unit[1750]{lb}(\unit[3]{ft}+\unit[14]{ft}+\unit[6]{ft}+\unit[2]{ft}) &= \unit[43\;750]{ft\cdot lb} \vspace{.0625in} \\
            M_B &= \unit[10\;500]{ft\cdot lb} + \unit[93\;500]{ft\cdot lb} +  \unit[43\;750]{ft\cdot lb} &=  \unit[147\;750]{ft\cdot lb}
        \end{aligned}$$
    \end{solution}
\end{problem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This approach seems to do the trick. Are there any consequence or benefits to using minipage in this context, other than that it just works of course! Thank you.

Comment: One difference with respect to `tabular` is that now the parts of the problem can move to the second page. You can't break a minipage in the middle though (and if you want to you'll have to find another minipage like command like `tcolorbox` for that).

Comment: Or `itemize` as it was suggested by @egreg. Note though that if you start an item by a display formula `\item` introduces an additional vertical gap.

Answer (score 2):

The outer `tabular` isn't really helping, but if you want a table, you could do something like this, using an environment syntax for the parts is particularly tricky if you are embedding in a table as each cell is then a separate group and you are starting an environment in one cell and ending in another.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\newenvironment{problem}{%%
    \noindent
    \hspace{-1in}%
    \begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l p{5.5in}}%%
}{%%
    \end{tabular}%%
    \par
    \pagebreak
}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}
\setlength\extrarowheight{.125in}

    \begin{problem}
Given&
 The weights of the various components of the truck are show in the sketch below.
\\

Asked&
 Replace this system of forces by an equialent resultant force
and specify its location measured from $B$.
\\

Sketch&
\begin{center} PUT PICTURE HERE \end{center}
\\

Equations&
{\begin{align*}
            \sum F_{x_I} &= \sum F_{x_{II}}
            \sum F_{y_I} &= \sum F_{y_{II}}
            \sum M_{o_I} &= \sum M_{o_{II}}
\end{align*}}

            \vspace{.0625 in}

            \[M_o = F\times d_\perp\]
\\

Solutions&
{\begin{align*}
            \sum F_x &= F_{x_1} + F_{x_2} + F_{x_3} = 0\\
            \sum F_y &= F_{y_1} + F_{y_2} + F_{y_3} = 
\unit[3500]{lb} + \unit[5500] {lb} + \unit[1750]{lb} = \unit[10\;750]{lb}
\end{align*}}

            \vspace{.0625 in}

            {\begin{align*}
\sum M_B = M_1 + M_2 + M_3\\
                M_1 &= F\times d_\perp = \unit[3500]{lb}(\unit[3]{ft}) &= \unit[10\;500]{ft\cdot lb} \\
                M_2 &= F\times d_\perp = \unit[5500]{lb}(\unit[3]{ft}+\unit[14]{ft}) &= \unit[93\;500]{ft\cdot lb} \\
                M_3 &= F\times d_\perp = \unit[1750]{lb}(\unit[3]{ft}+\unit[14]{ft}+\unit[6]{ft}+\unit[2]{ft}) &= \unit[43\;750]{ft\cdot lb} \vspace{.0625in} \\
                M_B &= \unit[10\;500]{ft\cdot lb} + \unit[93\;500]{ft\cdot lb} +  \unit[43\;750]{ft\cdot lb} &=  \unit[147\;750]{ft\cdot lb}
            \end{align*}}

    \end{problem}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it as a `description environment` with specialised items (`\Given`, `\Asked`,&c.), put in an `\eqparbox` so they all use the largest  width of them. In addition, I replaced the many `$$ … $$`, which you should not use with latex, with the relevant `amsmath` environments. Note this environment can break across pages.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, units}
\usepackage{enumitem, eqparbox}%%%
\newlength\itemwd
\settowidth{\itemwd}{\textbf{Equations}}
\newcommand\Given{\item[\eqparbox{Pb}{Given: }]\leavevmode}
\newcommand\Asked{\item[\eqparbox{Pb}{Asked: }]\leavevmode}
\newcommand\Sketch{\item[\eqparbox{Pb}{Sketch: }]\leavevmode}
\newcommand\Eqns{\item[\eqparbox{Pb}{Equations: }]\leavevmode}
\newcommand\Sol{\item[\eqparbox{Pb}{Solution: }]\leavevmode}

 \begin{document}

\begin{description}[leftmargin =\eqboxwidth{Pb},labelsep = 0pt]

    \Given The weights of the various components of the truck are show in the sketch below. \\

    \Asked Replace this system of forces by an equialent resultant force and specify its location measured from $B$. \\

    \Sketch
        \begin{center}PUT PICTURE HERE\end{center}

    \Eqns \vspace{-\dimexpr\abovedisplayskip+\baselineskip\relax}
    \begin{align*}\sum F_{x_I} & = \sum F_{x_{II}}\\%
    \sum F_{y_I} & = \sum F_{y_{II}}\\%
    \sum M_{o_I} & = \sum M_{o_{II}}
       \\[2ex]
        M_o & = F\times d_\perp
\end{align*}
   \Sol \vspace{-\dimexpr\abovedisplayskip+\baselineskip\relax}%
   \begin{gather*}\sum F_x = F_{x_1} + F_{x_2} + F_{x_3} = 0\\
            \sum F_y = F_{y_1} + F_{y_2} + F_{y_3} = \unit[3500]{lb} + \unit[5500] {lb} + \unit[1750]{lb} = \unit[10\;750]{lb}\\[2ex]
           \sum M_B = M_1 + M_2 + M_3\\[2ex]
   \begin{alignedat}{2}
 M_1 &= F\times d_\perp = \unit[3500]{lb}(\unit[3]{ft}) & &= \unit[10\;500]{ft\cdot lb} \\
 M_2 &= F\times d_\perp = \unit[5500]{lb}(\unit[3]{ft}+\unit[14]{ft}) & &= \unit[93\;500]{ft\cdot lb} \\
 M_3 &= F\times d_\perp = \unit[1750]{lb}(\unit[3]{ft}+\unit[14]{ft}+\unit[6]{ft}+\unit[2]{ft}) & &= \unit[43\;750]{ft\cdot lb} \\[2ex]
 M_B &= \unit[10\;500]{ft\cdot lb} + \unit[93\;500]{ft\cdot lb} + \unit[43\;750]{ft\cdot lb} & & = \unit[147\;750]{ft\cdot lb}
 \end{alignedat}
\end{gather*}%

\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]