# how to insert empty 2in lines like squared notepad paper

Tags: line

Please help me.
how to insert empty 2in lines like squared notepad paper
Looks like That Image[image]

Comment: You will most likely get an answer if you post a minimal working example (MWE) that shows what you've tried so far.

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188164/how-to-use-latex-to-print-a-document-to-look-like-a-lined-notebook

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `tikz` package to do it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paralist} % solely for styling the enumerate list
\usepackage{tikz}     % for drawing the grid

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]

\item some text

\item some more text

% draw the grid. Using 3.0001in instead of 3.0 ensures the last
% vertical line gets drawn. 
\tikz{\draw[step=.1in,gray,thin] (0,0) grid (3.0001in,1.0001in);}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]