# How do I a beamer presentation to look like a lined notebook?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I was adapting the ideas found in [How to use Latex to print a document to look like a lined notebook?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188164/how-to-use-latex-to-print-a-document-to-look-like-a-lined-notebook)

to  a beamer presentation, but I can't able it.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please show us what you've tried so far as minimal, but compilable example?

Comment: \setbeamertemplate{background}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,yshift=10cm,transform shape]
     \foreach \fila in {1,...,20}
     {
      \draw [line width=1pt,color=notepadrule] 
      (current page.west|-1cm,-\fila*12pt) -- ++(\paperwidth,0);
     }
     \draw[overlay,red!70!black,line width=1pt]
     ([xshift=1pt]current page text area.west|-current page.north) --  
     ([xshift=1pt]current page text area.west|-current page.south);
     \end{tikzpicture}  }

but, the lined notebook is inverted.

Answer (score 4):

Squared paper instead of lined:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setbeamertemplate{background}[grid][step=13.6]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \vspace{-0.2cm}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Based on samcarters answer, I wrote a new background template `lines`. It has the same options as the `grid` template.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newdimen\beamer@bglines@y
\defbeamertemplate{background}{lines}[1][]
{%
  \setkeys{beamer@backgroundgrid}{step=0.5cm,color=fg!10!bg}%
  \setkeys{beamer@backgroundgrid}{#1}%
  \begin{pgfpicture}{0cm}{0cm}{\the\paperwidth}{\the\paperheight}
    \beamer@bggc
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\beamer@bglines@num}{int(\the\paperheight/\beamer@bggw)}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,\beamer@bglines@num}{
        \pgfmathsetlength{\beamer@bglines@y}{\y*\beamer@bggw}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{\the\beamer@bglines@y}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\the\paperwidth}{\the\beamer@bglines@y}}
    }
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{background}[lines][step=13.6]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \vspace{-0.2cm}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]