Display Issue with Handwriting Simulation
I wanted to make my LaTeX notes look handwritten. I found an approach from this site which uses:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[subdued]{mathastext}
\MTfamily{augie}
\Mathastext[augie]

\newenvironment{Handwriting}{\MTversion{augie}}{\par}

\begin{document}
     \begin{Handwriting}
     This is the number $0$ in handwriting mode.
     
     This is the letter O in handwriting mode.
     \end{Handwriting}
\end{document}

My biggest problem with this is that the number zero looks like the letter O when compiled. They look almost indistinguishable:

Is there a way to correct this?

They also look the same in my own handwriting, so maybe that's a feature not a bug. :-)

Please can you include a link? 'This site' has a horrible search function - finding things is like searching for needles in haystacks. (Actually, more like one needle in several haystacks.)

The way to correct it is to use a different font, at least for maths. You may want your notes to look handwritten, but using augie for maths is never going to give you good results. You'll just have a hotch-potch of augie-mixed-with-other-things. I mean, they're your notes, but why make them difficult to decipher?

It is easy to distinguish: Letter O looks Left, numbeR 0 looks Right. :-)

You could do away with the letter (as in the children's story The Wonderful O). I wouldn't recommend doing without zero unless you're a historian.

The previous post that shows this approach is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/453429/create-a-handwriting-environment-for-both-text-and-math.
