I want this type of layout design for my document

Can someone help me latex code for this type of layout for A4 Paper? I want to get black margin left on odd page and right on even page. Longing for expert's help. Thanks.

Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188164/how-to-use-latex-to-print-a-document-to-look-like-a-lined-notebook could help

Are you just looking to make the black margins, or do you want the gray lines, black border, rounded corners, etc.?

both the black margins and lines

Here is a TikZ-less version; you can play around with the parameters as you wish. It has the side effect of going right through the page number, but I suspect you don't actually want the page numbers and the lines that far down anyway:
\documentclass[twoside,openright,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newlength{\blackmargin}
\setlength{\blackmargin}{1em}
\newlength{\cornerradius}
\setlength{\cornerradius}{4mm}
\newlength{\offset}
\setlength{\offset}{0pt}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}
{
  % Draw the black margins
  \linethickness{\blackmargin}%
  \ifodd\value{page}
    \setlength{\offset}{0pt}
    \put(\dimexpr\paperwidth - 0.5\blackmargin\relax,0)
        {\line (0,-1) {\paperheight}}
  \else
    \setlength{\offset}{\blackmargin}
    \put(0.5\blackmargin,0) {\line (0,-1) {\paperheight}}
  \fi
  % Draw the gray lines
  \linethickness{0.5pt}%
  \multiput (\dimexpr 3mm + \offset, -1.9cm)
    (0,-\baselineskip){65}
    {\color{lightgray}
     \line (1,0) {\dimexpr \paperwidth - \blackmargin - 6mm\relax}}

  % Draw border
  \linethickness{1pt}%
    \put (0.5\paperwidth,-1mm) {\line (1,0)
      {\dimexpr 0.5\paperwidth - \blackmargin - \cornerradius + \offset\relax}}
    \qbezier (\dimexpr\paperwidth-\blackmargin-\cornerradius+\offset\relax,-1mm)
             (\dimexpr\paperwidth-\blackmargin-1mm+\offset\relax,-1mm)
             (\dimexpr\paperwidth-\blackmargin-1mm+\offset\relax,
              \dimexpr -\cornerradius - 1mm)
    \put (\dimexpr\paperwidth-\blackmargin-1mm+\offset,
          \dimexpr -\cornerradius - 1mm)
        {\line (0,-1) {\dimexpr \paperheight-2mm-2\cornerradius}}
    \qbezier (\dimexpr\paperwidth-\blackmargin-1mm+\offset,
                \dimexpr-\paperheight+\cornerradius+1mm)
             (\dimexpr\paperwidth-\blackmargin-1mm+\offset,
                \dimexpr-\paperheight+1mm)
             (\dimexpr\paperwidth-\blackmargin-\cornerradius-1mm+\offset\relax,
                \dimexpr-\paperheight+1mm)
    \put (\dimexpr\paperwidth-\blackmargin-1mm-\cornerradius+\offset,
          \dimexpr -\paperheight + 1mm)
        {\line (-1,0) {\dimexpr \paperwidth-\blackmargin-2mm-2\cornerradius}}
    \qbezier (\dimexpr 1mm+\cornerradius+\offset\relax,
              \dimexpr -\paperheight + 1mm\relax)
             (\dimexpr 1mm+\offset\relax, \dimexpr -\paperheight + 1mm\relax)
             (\dimexpr 1mm+\offset\relax,
                \dimexpr -\paperheight + 1mm + \cornerradius\relax)
    \put (\dimexpr1mm+\offset\relax,
            \dimexpr-\paperheight+\cornerradius+1mm\relax)
        {\line (0,1) {\dimexpr \paperheight-2mm-2\cornerradius}}
    \qbezier (\dimexpr 1mm+\offset\relax,
              \dimexpr -1mm-\cornerradius\relax)
             (\dimexpr 1mm+\offset\relax,-1mm)
             (\dimexpr 1mm+\cornerradius+\offset\relax,-1mm)
    \put (0.5\paperwidth,-1mm) {\line (-1,0)
      {\dimexpr 0.5\paperwidth - \cornerradius - \offset\relax}}
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}

